# Insert default text into newly created files using vscod extension api

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to create a simple vscode extension that will insert some default text into a newly created file. What I want is for the `vscode.workspace.createFileSystemWatcher` to call a function that gets the `activeTextEditor` and writes to the new file. Here is what I've tried:

```
import * as vscode from "vscode";
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
  let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand(
    "default-text-generator.generate",
    () => {
      function _watcherChangeApplied(editor?: vscode.TextEditor) {
        if (editor) {
          editor.edit((editBuilder) => {
            editBuilder.insert(editor.selection.active, "Hello World");
          });
        }
      }

      const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
      let uri: vscode.Uri | undefined = editor?.document.uri;

      if (uri) {
        let watcher = vscode.workspace.createFileSystemWatcher(
          new vscode.RelativePattern(
            vscode.workspace.getWorkspaceFolder(uri)!,
            "**/*.ts"
          ),
          false,
          false,
          false
        );

        watcher.onDidCreate(() => _watcherChangeApplied(editor));
      }
    }
  );

  context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}

// this method is called when your extension is deactivated
export function deactivate(): void {
  //deactivate
}
```

Here's what's happening. The editor seems to insert the text, then immediately gets overwritten back to a blank page. I can't seem to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

The problem happens because the `editor` you are referring to is not what you think to be. It is not the *newly created editor* but instead, the editor that you are focused/active when the new `.ts` file is created.

The `FileSystemWatcher.onDidCreate` event provides you a `Uri` to the newly created file inside your workspace, but not necessarily opened in VS Code. Try creating a file via terminal and you will see what I mean. The file is created, the event is fired, but no editor is opened in VS Code.

So, you won't be able to use the `editor.edit` API to manipulate the file. Instead, you should edit the file using RAW/Node functions. But, in this case, maybe/probably you will clash with the external tool that is creating the `.ts` file (which may not be VS Code, if you use the FileWatcher). If only files created via VS Code must be detected, you should change to the `workspace.onDidCreateFiles` event instead. But yet, it also only provides you the `Uri`, not the `Editor`.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```js
let disposable2 = vscode.commands.registerCommand('yourCommand.here', async  (...file) =>  {

  async function _watcherChangeApplied(uri) {
    if (uri) {

      const editor = await vscode.window.showTextDocument(uri);

      editor.edit((editBuilder) => {
        editBuilder.insert(editor.selection.active, "Hello World");
      });
      await editor.document.save();
    }
  }
    
  const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
  let uri = editor?.document.uri;
    
  if (uri) {
    let watcher = vscode.workspace.createFileSystemWatcher(
        new vscode.RelativePattern(
            vscode.workspace.getWorkspaceFolder(uri),
            "**/*.ts"
        ),
        false,
        false,
        false
    );
    
    // watcher.onDidCreate(() => _watcherChangeApplied(editor));
    watcher.onDidCreate((uri) => _watcherChangeApplied(uri));
  }
}
```

The key point is that `watcher.onDidCreate()` will return the uri of the newly created file.  You can pass that to your `_watcherChangeApplied(uri)` function.

In `_watcherChangeApplied(uri)` you can show the created file via `await vscode.window.showTextDocument(uri)` and that function returns an `editor` that you can use with its `edit` functions.

The code works whether you create the file within vscode (like the `New File...` icon button at the top of the explorer) or via the terminal (like `touch test.ts`).

---

If you want to enable creating new files through the terminal, for example, and NOT open them, try this `_watcherChangeApplied(uri)`:

```js
async function _watcherChangeApplied(uri) {
  if (uri) {

    const document = await vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(uri);

    const strToAdd = "Hello World";
    const wse = new vscode.WorkspaceEdit();
    wse.insert(uri, new vscode.Position(0,0), strToAdd);
    await vscode.workspace.applyEdit(wse);

    await document.save();
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this?  Did it work for you?